# How to set MFC time/date control to 24 hour time

Tags: c++, mfc, time

I am trying to get a CDateTimeCtrl control in a dlg box to show 24 hour time format rather than am/pm nonsense.

I would have thought there was a flag for this, but MS decided NOT to provide one.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though `CDateTimeCtrl` doesn't provide a class method to change the format, the class itself wraps the Win32 [date and time picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which does allow you to set a custom format. You can do this by sending a message directly to the control:

```
DateTime_SetFormat(m_dateTime.m_hWnd, TEXT("HH:mm:ss"));
```

**Edit:** As @Kirill V. Lyadvinsky points out, you can simply use the `CDateTimeCtrl::SetFormat` method -- I somehow missed that when I was looking at the reference.

Comment: Just use [`m_dateTime.SetFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5f7wz2(v=VS.100).aspx), no need to use pure WinAPI.

Comment: @Kirill: Good find, I somehow missed that method.